# Hide/Enable adMob

Tags: android, admob

I searched for but couldnt get answers

I'm calling the admob this way:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Ok, but how can I turn invisible the admob? (Including the view) And after be able to enable again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Edit:
You can also set it to `adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`.The difference between `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` is that `GONE` removes the view completely from the layout while `INVISIBLE` "saves" the space this view takes.

Comment: Are you sure? Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE). Does `View.Invisible` work?